# Inserir botao dinamicamente em RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, button

Eu tenho um ListView e quero adicionar um botão do lado de cada item da lista, mas tem que ser dinamicamente:

item_listview.xml

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout">

<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/vermelho"
        android:src="@drawable/lixobotao"
        android:id="@+id/btnexcluir"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnfavorito"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/amarelo"
        android:src="@drawable/estrelabotao"
        android:id="@+id/btnfavorito"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:id="@+id/texto1"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
        android:id="@+id/texto2"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/texto1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
        android:id="@+id/texto3"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/texto2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

lista.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lisview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#FFECECEC"
        android:dividerHeight="2sp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn">
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="SALVAR"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Como faço para que o botão fique ao lado de cada item? Quero que apareça igual a esse botão verde da imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei deixar invisível como sugeriram e não deu certo:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStade){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceStade);
        setContentView(R.layout.listas);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                View v;
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_listas,null);
                ImageButton favorito = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnfavorito);
                ImageButton excluir = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnexcluir);
                favorito.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));
                favorito.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                excluir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: O ideal é você colocar ele no layout normalmente e setar como invisível, e depois via código você aparece com ele ou não.

Comment: Eu tentei, mas não estou conseguindo deixar o botão visível

Comment: Sua função de clique está funcionando? para testar mande exibir um toast, e se funcionar adicione no xml do botao visibility = GONE, assim ele não vai ocupar espaço, e daí embaixo do toast, tente setar o visibility = VISIBLE. tambem verifique se está com o id certo, faça testes, pois pode não estar conseguindo encontrar o botão.

Comment: Já fiz os testes e depurei. Aparentemente era pra estar funcionando

Comment: Não funcionou porque você está inflando o layout na hora do clique, e não utilizando a `View` correspondente ao seu item. Remova as duas primeiras linhas que você utiliza para inflar o layout, e substitua as outras linhas onde está `v` por `view`, pois o `onItemClick`já te passa `View` correspondente ao item que você clicou

Answer (score 0):

Respondendo a sua pergunta de como criar um `Button` no `RelativeLayout`, é simples, aqui está um exemplo de como fazer isso dinamicamente:

```
Button btTeste = new Button(this);
btTeste.setText("Teste");

RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout ) findViewById(R.id.seu_relative_layout);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rl.addView(btTeste, lp);
```

---

Quanto a sua outra dúvida referente a visibilidade do botão, eu deixei um comentário respondendo:

> Não funcionou porque você está inflando o layout na hora do clique, e
>   não utilizando a View correspondente ao seu item. Remova as duas
>   primeiras linhas que você utiliza para inflar o layout, e substitua as
>   outras linhas onde está `v` por `view`, pois o `onItemClick` já te passa View
>   correspondente ao item que você clicou

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ImageButton favorito = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnfavorito);
    ImageButton excluir = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnexcluir);
    favorito.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));
    favorito.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    excluir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: E se eu não tivesse a view? Pq vai ter uma hora que vou ter que fazer isso dentro de um SwipeListView e nesse evento a View não é passada como parâmetro. Se eu inflasse antes do evento daria certo?